# How do I test custom UINavigationController behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, uinavigationcontroller, tdd

I'm trying to test some UINavigationController custom subclass delegate behaviors on my tests but delegate methods never fire inside tests. I've already tried setting appdelegate window rootViewController to the navigation and accessed the .view property but pushing a view controller never fires the willShow delegate method.

It's called on non test app (running the app and navigating).

Here's a code example:

```
let firstController = UIViewController()
let secondController = UIViewController()
let navigationController = BurgerNavigationController(rootViewController: firstController)
navigationController.pushViewController(secondController, animated: true)
expect(secondController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem).notTo(beNil())
```

I expect navigation controller to call it's

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
```

delegate method. It's called when running the app but I can't figure out how to test it.

Here's the custom init of UINavigationController I'm using:

```
override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
    super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    delegate = self
}
```

And the delegate method implemented but never called in that same class:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    //Code here never called on tests but called on real app
}
```

Comment: Please, provide some code. It's hard to say something without it.

Comment: Could you also share relevant portions of your custom navigation controller?

Comment: I've added more code, hope you can help. It's a really simple controller, works in real app but not on unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue. UINavigationController delegate is async so you should wait for it to be called.

In my case I'm using Nimble for tests so using `.toEventually` instead of `.to` worked. It waits now for the expectation to be true.